# How to do two job by a column using cursor in oracle sql?

Tags: oracle, cursor

I have a `hata` table with the following data;

```
| sube  |  error_message |
--------------------------
|  5    |   sdadasdasdas |
|  5    |   sadadsadasda |
|  7    |   sadsadaslkgk |
|  7    |  aasdasdkfsjdj |
|  9    |   sjsjfjssdf   |
```

I have following cursor;

```
current_sube    NUMBER := 0;

CURSOR c_error
   IS 
   select sube, error_message
   from hata
   order by sube;
```

I am fetching this like

```
OPEN c_error;
    LOOP
    BEGIN

    FETCH c_error INTO hata_mail; 

    ----
    IF hata_mail.sube = current_sube
       add row to array;

    ELSE 
         do my job;
         empty array;
         current_sube = hata_mail.sube;

    ----

    END;
    END LOOP;

CLOSE c_error;
```

My question starts from `FETCH` statement.

For each row that is fetched, if `sube` column and `current_sube` is same then add row to an array, else do my specific job and empty array.

This logic works until last row because in last row, there is an unempty array and I couldn't my specific job.

Is there any suggestion to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `current_sube` variable before `fetch` statement and check the last row using `cursor%rowcount`.